# Constructor that produces compile time errors depending on parameter values

Tags: c++

I have a class `C` and want to do the following:

```
class C {
public:
    C(const size_t aa, const size_t bb) { // aa and bb are compile time constants
    // when aa + bb > 10 raise a compile time error
    }
private:
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
}
```

Constructor `C::C` should type check and reject any `aa` and `bb` values that are not known at compile-time and are not positive integers. If that check passes, the compiler should check their sum. If the sum is greater than 10, the compiler should reject the constructor call.

Is this doable (and how) using only ISO C++11, not relying on the specific compiler?

Comment: It is not possible if `aa` and `bb` are passed as regular parameters, but you can do it with a `static_assert` if you pass them as template parameters to `C`.

Comment: [std::integral_constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant)?

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry but it's not obvious to me how. As far as I can see `std::integral_constant` takes a type and a value of that type. I don't want to give the value upfront. The idea is for the caller of `C::C` to provide the value.

Comment: @0x5453 Thanks. But, again, I don't see exactly how. Note that I need to perform + on the two parameters in compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At **compile-time**, what you are asking for is possible only with templates, eg:

```cpp
template<size_t aa, size_t bb>
class C {
public:
    C() {
        static_assert(aa > 0, "aa must be > 0");
        static_assert(bb > 0, "bb must be > 0");
        static_assert((aa + bb) <= 10, "aa + bb must be <= 10");
    }
};
```

```cpp
C<1, 2> c1; // OK
C<5, 6> c2; // compile error
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/3c7G9I)

Otherwise, at **run-time**, all you can do is throw an exception on bad input, eg:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>

class C {
public:
    C(const size_t aa, const size_t bb) : a(aa), b(bb) {
        if (aa == 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("aa must be > 0");
        if (bb == 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("bb must be > 0");
        if ((aa + bb) > 10) {
            throw std::runtime_error("aa + bb must be <= 10");
        }
    }
private:
    size_t a;       
    size_t b;
};
```

```
C c1(1, 2); // OK
C c2(5, 6); // runtime error
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/KPJ75U)

Answer (score 1):

Parameter values are not constexpr, so cannot be used in constant expression, but types can:

```
class C {
public:
    template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
    constexpr C(std::integral_constant<size_t, N1>,
                std::integral_constant<size_t, N2>) : a(N1), b(N2)
    {
        static_assert(N1 + N2 <= 10);
    }
private:
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
};
```

With usage

```
C c_KO{std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 40>{}, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2>{}}; // KO
C c_OK{std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 4>{}, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 2>{}}; // OK
```

UDL might allow to reduce verbosity:

```
template <char ... Digits>
constexpr std::size_t compute_value()
{
     std::size_t res = 0;

     for (auto digit : {Digits...}) {
          if (digit < '0' || '9' < digit) throw std::domain_error("Invalid number");

          res *= 10;
          res += digit - '0';
     }
     return res;
}

template <char ... Digits>
constexpr std::integral_constant<std::size_t, compute_value<Digits...>()>
operator "" _c() { return {}; }
```

With usage

```
C c_KO{40_c, 2_c}; // KO
C c_OK{4_c, 2_c}; // OK
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09abd94d4e6c0fb7)

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42, this is a very useful answer too.